# Create legend with OpenLayers 3 / GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, legend

I am using OpenLayers 3 and GeoServer to create a map. I would like to create a legend for the map that I have created. I've been looking for a good example I could base my map legend off of, but was struggling to do so. I used the following GetLegendGraphic to get the legend I wanted:

`http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=cite:censustractsum&STYLE=basicstyle9&`

However, I have no idea how to display this using OpenLayers 3. Is there any way for me to create a legend without having to use anything else. If OL3 can't do this, could I use GeoExt? All the examples of GeoExt I saw were with OpenLayers 2, and I wasn't sure if GeoExt would work with OpenLayers 3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just want to display a static legend you can just put your request into an img-tag:

```
 <div id="legend">
        <img src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=cite:censustractsum&STYLE=basicstyle9">
 </div>
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/od5eLpb9/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a js fiddle with a floating legend:
http://jsfiddle.net/od5eLpb9/46/

Answer (score 0):

Geoext isn't and will probably never be update for ol3.

[www.geoext.org/pipermail/users/2014-June/003415.html](http://www.geoext.org/pipermail/users/2014-June/003415.html)

Comment: It is updated ol 4.4